SQL aggregate SUM function not outputting correctly?
I have three tables: crash_table contains the numbers of car crashes on each day from 2009 to 2024, date_table contains date information (which i'm using to get the year out of the date values in crash_table), and population_table contains the total population for each year.



Date
Severity
Crashes




1/1/2009
Property Damage Only
66


1/1/2009
Major Injury
2


11/5/2017
Minor Injury
10



and so on.
The date table looks like this:



Date
Year
Month
Day of Week




1/1/2009
2009
January
Thursday


1/2/2009
2009
January
Friday



and so on.
The population table looks like this:



Year
Population




2009
3,032,870


2010
3,050,819



and so on.
My goal is to get a table which shows each year, and the estimated per-capita car crash rate for each year. To that end, I've written the following SQL query:
SELECT p.Year, 
    (SUM(c.Crashes) / ANY_VALUE(p.Population)) AS `Crashes per Capita`
FROM crash_table c
INNER JOIN date_table d ON c.Date = d.Date
INNER JOIN population_table p ON d.Year = p.Year
WHERE p.Year != 2024
GROUP BY p.Year;

I put ANY.VALUE() around population in the SELECT statement to avoid errors caused by the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY setting.
The table output I'm getting from this query is clearly incorrect; the 'Crashes per Capita' column values are all in the tens of thousands, while I'm expecting values that are far less than zero.
The result table looks like this:



Year
Crashes per Capita




2009
18498


2010
18132



I'm expecting the per-capita values to land in the realm of 0.01 to 0.02, or so.
Is the issue with the aggregate function in the SELECT statement, or am I missing something else? Apologies if this is something obvious - I'm a relative beginner and I couldn't find any similar questions with answers that worked for me.

Please post sample data and the expected result.

If there are multiple matching rows in date_table or population_table, the sum will be multiplied by the number of matches.

E.g. if population_table has a row for every day of the year, the sum will be multiplied by 365. And you'll pick a random date's population with ANY_VALUE().

I added the sample data and results. I hope I was clear enough on what I'm looking for. I can see how the JOIN statement might be causing problems, but I'm unsure of how to get to where I'm trying to go.

If the population column has comma as thousands separator, then that column is a string not a number. Convert it to a number by removing the thousand separators and I guess it should work.

That seems to have done it, Shadow! I did not notice that SQL had imported population as a text variable. Thank you so much!

Thanks to Shadow, the answer was just that the population variable was cast incorrectly as text instead of as an int. Thank you everyone!
